# Raspberry Pi 2B missing RAM

Tags: pi-2

weird thing here. I noticed my Pi model 2B is reporting a smaller amount of available RAM than before (~700Mb vs 1Gb).

```
[root@raspberry ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            679         166          33           1         479         498
Swap:             0           0           0
[root@raspberry ~]#
```

Is my RAM module degrading over time? Is this a known issue with older Pies? Thanks

Comment: Edit in the output from `vcgencmd get_mem gpu`.

Comment: OMG you are right. I am so silly. That "missing" memory is assigned to the GPU. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@goldilocks gave me the answer. That "missing" memory is just assigned to the GPU

Comment: Note: In most cases, the CPU/OS will not be able to handle deffective RAM gracefully. It will just randomly crash or not boot at all.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.